# How to get only the year part of a date string?

Tags: php, date

I have an input date by user like this: `1979-06-13`

Now, i want to compare the year:

```
foreach ($list as $key) {
    $year = 1979;
    if ($key > $year) { //only the year
        echo (error);
        }
}
```

How can I get only the year?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
$year = strtok($date, '-');
```

If you want the year as integer, you can also use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$year = intval($date);
```

Answer (score 27):

Probably more expensive, but possibly more flexible, use strtotime() to convert to a timestamp and date() to extract the part of the date you want.

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime($in_date));
```

Comment: `$year = date('Y', strtotime("2012"));` is giving me 2013 right now with php 5.2.

Comment: I think the `idate` function is more appropriate than `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Heres an easy and exact way.

```
//suppose
$dateProvided="1979-06-13";
//get first 4 characters only
$yearOnly=substr($dateProvided,0,4);
echo $yearOnly;
//1979
```

and one more thing to know, in some cases like, for example when the date is like 2010-00-00 the date function don't work as expected, it would return 2009 instead of 2010.
heres an example

```
//suppose
$dateProvided="2010-00-00";
$yearOnly = date('Y', strtotime($dateProvided));
//we expect year to be 2010 but the value of year would be 2009
echo $yearOnly;
//2009
```

Answer (score 1):

you could explode the date.

```
$inputDate = "1979-06-13";
$myDate = 1979;
$datePieces = explode("-",$inputDate);
if (intval($datePieces[0]) > $myDate){
  echo "error";
};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php